# how to set document id of users in firebase using this code in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I know im asking too many stupid question but please help me out if possible, so i am using this code to send data to firebase:

```
            try {
                const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
                  owner_uid: authUser.user.uid,
                  username: username,
                  email: authUser.user.email,
                  profile_pic: await randomProfiles()
                });
                console.log("CREATED");
           

     this.props.phase(0);
                  } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                  }
                } catch (error) {
                  console.log(error);
                }
              };
```

I cannot figure out how to set the doc id using this code. it was written by a friend. I read the documentation of firebase but i cant figure out how to implement this in to my code :

```
     db.collection("users")
      .doc(authUser.user.email)({
        owner_uid: authUser.user.uid,
        username: username,
        email: authUser.user.email
      })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firebase version 9, in order to specify the document id when adding a document do this:

```
const users = collection(db, "users")
await setDoc(doc(db, users, authUser.user.email), data);
```

Check [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document) for more information.